# Set-Cookie not set cookies in my browser (React + Sanctum)

Tags: reactjs, laravel, csrf, laravel-sanctum

I am using Laravel sanctum to make auth With ReactJS
in cors.php. I have set these values

```
'paths' => ['api/*', 'api/csrf-cookie','/login'],
'supports_credentials' => true,
```

sanctum.php

```
'prefix'=>'api'
```

in React I use axios with credintials

```
axios.get('http://www.react.test/api/csrf-cookie').then(response => {
        console.log(response);
 }, { withCredentials: true });
```

when using Postman, I get the Set-Cookie Value , but when I try to use browser its not set in my browser under Application->cookies tab

- Laravel domain

```
http://www.react.test/
```

- React domain

```
http://localhost:3000/
```

Comment: I am not sure, I saw a similar question a few hours ago, but I think it is related to CORS, you are "talking" between 2 different domains, so cookies cannot be created except CORS explicitly allows this to happen for THAT domain or ALL domains.

Comment: @matiaslauriti  he needs to use the axios package properly, after that, CORS is not the issue here

Comment: @cEthar I have answered your question,  you can mark it as answered and upvote it if this solved your issue, thankyou

Comment: @SachinAnanthakumar oh, I know about `withCredentials` but I thought for a moment that you could pass it like the author was doing...

Comment: @matiaslauriti, you can't pass it like that,  the author passed it as a second argument to `then`,  The second argument to `then` is for error, refer [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)

Comment: please mark the answer as answered if it solves the problem, thankyou!

Comment: @SachinAnanthakumar no its not solved, when i put link in browser directly, its work successfully, but the problem when use axios.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `axios` package wrong, `withCredentials` should be given as a `config options` to `axios` and not a `then`,

Change your code to this

```
axios.get('http://www.react.test/api/csrf-cookie',{ withCredentials: true }) // FIX
.then(response => {
    console.log(response);
}).catch((err)=>{
   console.log(err);
});
```

This will work fine now

For more refer to [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by changing the domain from 'http://www.react.test/api/csrf-cookie
to
http://localhost:8000/api/csrf-cookie

I think domain must be https if it's not a localhost.

Answer (score 0):

#### cookies only work for the same domain or subdomain for security reasons